# Difference between 'Just' and 'pure'

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative

```
Just (+) <*> Just 3 <*> Just 5
```

> Just 8

```
pure (+) <*> Just 3 <*> Just 5
```

> Just 8

```
pure (*3) <*> [0..10]
```

> [0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30]

```
Just (*3) <*> [0..10]
```

> Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘Maybe’
>
> Expected type: Maybe b
>
> Actual type: [b]
>
> In the second argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely ‘[0 .. 10]’
>
> In the expression: Just (* 3) <*> [0 .. 10]
>
> In an equation for ‘it’: it = Just (* 3) <*> [0 .. 10]

When are `pure` and `Just` interchangeable and when are they different?

Answer (score 11):

`pure` is an overloaded operation. It is defined for all types that implement the `Applicative` class. One of the types that do that is `Maybe`. So `pure` in that context is the same as `Just`. But there are other types that also implement `Applicative` such as `[]` (lists). In that case, `pure` means singleton (i.e. the function that takes a single value and returns the one-element list that contains that value). So

```
pure (*3) <*> [0..10]
```

really means:

```
[(*3)] <*> [0..10]
```

and not

```
Just (*3) <*> [0..10]
```

In this last example you are trying to mix lists with maybes which is why GHC rejects it. In general, haskell figures out what is the exact meaning of `pure` based on the context, e.g. if you try to use it with maybes, it will interpret it as `Just`, if you use it with lists interpret it as singleton.

Answer (score 7):

The `pure` function returns a polymorphic value:

```
Prelude> :t pure "foo"
pure "foo" :: Applicative f => f [Char]
```

For `Maybe`, `pure` is just defined to be `Just`:

```
instance Applicative Maybe where
    pure = Just
    -- ...
```

Other types provide different definitions; as an example, it is defined for lists as

```
instance Applicative [] where
    pure x    = [x]
    -- ...
```

Specifying a type for the return value tells Haskell which `Applicative` instance to use for the definition of `pure`.

```
Prelude> pure "foo" :: [[Char]]
["foo"]
Prelude> pure "foo" :: Maybe [Char]
Just "foo"
```

In addition to providing an explicit type, Haskell can infer which type to use base on how the value is used. For instance, `(<*> [1..5]) :: (Num a, Enum a) => [a -> b] -> [b]`, so in `pure (+3) <*> [1..5]`, we know `pure (+3)` has to have type `[a -> b]`. Similarly, in `pure (+3) <*> Just 5`, we know that `pure (+3)` must have type `Maybe (a->b)`.

In general, in any expression `pure f <*> g`, the type of `g` will determine what type of value `pure f` needs to return.